# Passing HTML page to template in Flask

Tags: flask

Lets say that I have an HTML page containing some small HTML code.How can I pass an HTML page itself to a template in flask? I know that we can pass some html content to a template(we can use Markup('String here'). But if I have the name of the HTML page, how can I do it?

Comment: Is this HTML page inside of `/templates` or is it elsewhere on disk, or is it somewhere on the internet?

Comment: Actually I am creating a flask extension so I want the users to use my html script inside of theirs. So, the html page is inside the templates folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the users to use a script of yours, simply register a blueprint on the app when your extension is initialized and ask the users to use an [`include`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#include) where the script should go:

```
{% include 'your-extension-name/your-script.html' %}
```

This assumes that your blueprint has a folder structure like this:

```
your_extension_name/
    __init__.py
    other
    files.here
    templates/
        your-extension-name/
            your-script.html
```

Alternately, you can use the approach taken by [Flask-DebugToolbar](https://github.com/mgood/flask-debugtoolbar/blob/82295aa4aa4b2083e2e707004cd95ce0f48a7819/flask_debugtoolbar/__init__.py#L169-208) and monkey-patch Flask's request / response handling to auto-inject your HTML (but that approach is a bit fragile and too long to place here).

Comment: And how can I refer to my css file which is in the static folder? This is because my html file contains a reference to a css file in the static folder.

Comment: Also could you please give some instructions on "register a blueprint on the app when your extension is initialized"? I read about the blueprints but I am still confused and not clear about how to do it. Can you please help?

Comment: `from flask import Blueprint` and then `your_extension_bp = Blueprint("your_extension_name", __name__, static_folder="static", template_folder="templates")`.  Then in your `init_app` you just call `register_blueprint` on the `app` object.  As for the static reference in your template, just use `url_for("your_extension_name.static", filename="you/file/here.ext")` and everything should work.

Comment: Thank You! It cannot be more clear than this. Thank You very much!

Comment: I am sorry but even though I write the url_for("your_extension_name.static", filename="you/file/here.ext"), the extension is looking for the static file in the user's application only. It is not looking it in the extension's static folder....

Comment: @DevilAtWork - that sounds like another question - what I gave you is [what's in the docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/blueprints/#static-files) so more details about your *current* setup will be needed in order to debug why it is not working.